# Angular add FormGroup to FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a parent component which is the main `FormGroup`. Inside this `<my-parent></my-parent>` component I have a child component, `<my-child></my-child>`.

The child component has a `*ngIf="some-conditional"`, and inside the child component, I have a quick fill button which basically does `patchValue` on a couple 
 of the child `FormGroup` controls.

It successfully adds the child `FormGroup` to parent `FormGroup`, but the values of the child inside of the parent are always empty.

I've tried to add the controls two ways(both unsuccessful), with a setter inside the parent component, and by emitting from inside the child component and reassigning the new value to the parent `FormGroup`.

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-with-child-form-groups?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts) with a demo of what im trying to do. Thanks in advance!

```js
// PARENT COMPONENT

import {
  Component,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

import {
  ChildComponent
} from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent {
  isChildFormSet = false;
  showChildComponent = false;
  exampleParentForm: FormGroup;

  // @ViewChild(ChildComponent)
  // set userForm(childForm: ChildComponent) {
  //   if (childForm && !this.isChildFormSet) {
  //     this.isChildFormSet = true;
  //     setTimeout(() => {
  //       this.exampleParentForm.addControl('child', new FormGroup(childForm.exampleChildForm.controls));
  //     });
  //   }
  // }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.exampleParentForm = this.fb.group({
      parent: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  submitForm(): void {
    console.log(this.exampleParentForm)
  }

  addChildComponent(): void {
    this.showChildComponent = true;
  }

  onChange(form) {
    // reset the form value to the newly emitted form group value.
    this.exampleParentForm = form;
  }
}


// CHILD COMPONENT

import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  exampleChildForm: FormGroup;

  @Input() formData: FormGroup;
  @Output() onFormGroupChange: EventEmitter < FormGroup > = new EventEmitter < FormGroup > ();


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exampleChildForm = this.fb.group({
      child: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.addGroupToParent();
  }

  fillWithText() {
    this.exampleChildForm.patchValue({
      child: 'This is an exmple.'
    });
  }

  clearText(): void {
    this.exampleChildForm.get('child').setValue('');
  }

  private addGroupToParent(): void {
    this.formData.addControl('child', new FormGroup(this.exampleChildForm.controls));
    this.onFormGroupChange.emit(this.formData);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- PARENT COMPONENT -->

<div class="parent-container">
  <form [formGroup]="exampleParentForm" (submit)="submitForm()" novalidate>
    <div class="col-3">
      <input class="effect-1" type="text" placeholder="Parent Input" formControlName="parent" />
      <span class="focus-border"></span>
    </div>
    <my-child *ngIf="showChildComponent" [formData]="exampleParentForm" (onFormGroupChange)="onChange($event)">
    </my-child>
    <div>
      <button class="button parent" type="submit">Log Form Value</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <button class="button small" type="button" (click)="addChildComponent()">Add Child Component</button>
</div>

<!-- CHILD COMPONENT -->

<div class="child-container" [formGroup]="exampleChildForm">
  <div class="col-3">
    <input class="effect-1" type="text" placeholder="Child Input" formControlName="child">
    <span class="focus-border"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button child" type="button" (click)="fillWithText()">Patch Value</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Instead of adding new FormGroup instance to the parent group simply add the child form group itself.

So

```
this.formData.addControl('child', new FormGroup(this.exampleChildForm.controls));
```

becomes

```
this.formData.addControl('child', this.exampleChildForm);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-with-child-form-groups-nzbdtn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.html)**

Comment: This seems to have done the job, thank you! Not sure why you were downvoted but I'd be interested to find out why,

Comment: I suspect you won't get the answer why I was downvoted since that's how SO users respect each other.